# Get part of a string using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string, for example `testserver\sho007`, how do I use jQuery to return only `sho007`?

Comment: jQuery is not meant to manipulate text/javascript. It's just used to access/hack/whatever the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply with javascript

```
 var my_string="testserver\sho007";
var left_side=my_string.split("\\")[0];
var right_side=my_string.split("\\")[1];
```

edited to add the double slash as Eric mentioned

Comment: Noticing how markdown is confused by "\", I'm curious if JavaScript would understand it, or if it should be `my_string.split("\\")[1]`?

Comment: Yes, you need the two slashes to make it work even in the assignment. In this case even the assignment will ignore the slash.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

> text.substring(fromindex,toindex)

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expressions if you are sure that the text you want is going to be after the slash.

Comment: Or maybe just `string.split('\')`?

Answer (score 0):

split the string using "\"  and get the position [1], always start with [0]

exp:

**html:**

```
<a class='test'>testserver\sho007</a>
```

**js:**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var a = $(".test").text();
       var aResult = a.split("\\")[1];
   });
```

testserver = [0]

sho007     = [1]